# Pulumi and Pulumi Azure Native not recognised in VS Code

Tags: python, azure, visual-studio-code, pulumi

**Problem**

VS Code doesn't seem to have recognised either of the following python libraries + no intellisense.

```py
import pulumi
from pulumi_azure_native import resources
from pulumi_azure_native import storage
...
```

VS Code highlights them with the **Import <library> could not be resolved** message. Also no suggestions are shown.

**Story**

I have started creating a Pulumi dev stack and I am wanting to do this in Python. I have initialised a Pulumi project which gives me the following hierarchy:

```sh
my-project
   ├─ venv
   ├─ __main.py__
   ├─ .gitignore
   ├─ Pulumi.dev.yaml
   ├─ Pulumi.yaml
   └─ requirements.txt
```

The modules already installed are `pulumi` and `pulumi-azure-native` as shown in the requirements.txt file:

```
pulumi>=3.0.0,<4.0.0
pulumi-azure-native>=1.0.0,<2.0.0
```

I have activated the virtual environment in which the above libraries are installed.

Answer (score 1):

the only way I did it work was adding `extraPaths` to on my `settings.json`:

```
{

  "python.analysis.extraPaths": ["/Users/bcarvalho/my-pulumi-project/infrastructure/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages"]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn to `venv\Lib\site-packages` and check if module exists.

If yes, add the following in `Workspace Settings.json`:

```
"python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {
        "reportMissingImports": "none"
    }
```

The warning should go away.

**UPDATE:**
[image: Intellisense works well]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, This will for sure disable the warning. But what should I do to get intellisense to work?

Comment: @FaithBaghan. Not familiar with the module, but typing `pulumi.` indeed follows suggestions like the screenshot in my post

Comment: @FaithBaghan. Turn to settings.json, both user and workspace, check if you add some settings that disable suggestions and intellisense. By the way, i use pylance as python language server.